# Как сохранить файл под определенным именем?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Набросал вот такой метод:

```
 static DownloadFileByLink(link: string, name: string) {
      let anchor = document.createElement('a');
      anchor.download = name;
      anchor.href = link;
      anchor.click();
      anchor.remove();
 }
```

Проблема в том, что название файла не меняется, хотя данный подход работал с blob-файлами.

Если это такая безопасность, то как-то не логично ввиду того, что я блоб-файлу все таки имя могу присвоить.

Comment: скачайте аяксом и сохраните уже как блоб

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это можно, НО в этом случае браузер не отображает прогресс скачки Это нужно свой прогресс бар рисовать...